# Prevent default values being submited to MVC3 controller with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, input

How can i have default values for my input's, and when user submites form, only values from changed inputs go to query, those that havent been change don't?

I have:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Persons", new AjaxOptions
{
   HttpMethod = "POST",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
   UpdateTargetId = "results",
   LoadingElementId = "progress"
}))

{
<input name="Name" type="text" class="cleardefault" value="First and Last name"/>
<input name="Adress" type="text" class="cleardefault" value="Adress"/>

<input name="Search" type="submit" class="mainSearchSubmit" value="submit" />  
}
```

I am using functions for clearing and replacing default text in
  `<input>` elements, by Ross Shannon, http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/

My goal is to only send values that are not default? This way when i breakpoint to my controller, my query has default values inside?? Is there a way to resolve this, and still keep MVC3 native code?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide full link to function you are using for clearing and replacing text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full answer: from [hagenburger.net](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Fill me …">
```

**JS**

```
//for older browsers

$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
     var input = $(this);
     if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
         input.val('');
         input.removeClass('placeholder');
     }
}).blur(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
}).blur();


$('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
             input.val('');
        }
    })
});
```

**CSS**

```
.placeholder
{
    color: #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `name` attribute from default fields. This way the default input fields  will not be submitted. After the value of default input field is changed, just add name attribute to it...

Hope I was clear enough...

Comment: I provided answer bellow, placeholder as an attribute resolves this... Cheers!

Comment: That's great.. But I think my answer differs from yours a little bit... Your solution will submit empty values for input fields that have default value.. My solution won't even submit default values.. Correct me if I am wrong... (Ups :) didn't see that you were the one who asked the question) :)